# javascript + jsf (2.0 jsp) + css not working basic image slide show!

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen1}"/>"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen2}"/>"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen3}"/>"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen4}"/>"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen5}"/>"
var image6=new Image()
image6.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen6}"/>"
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen1}"/>"
     alt="Imagen1" name="slide"/>
</body>
```

Comment: When having HTML/CSS/JS problems, you should not only pay attention to the JSF source code, but also to the generated output. Open the page in browser, rightclick, *View Source* and investigate it for syntax or logic/flow errors. If you stucks, post the generated output here as well. You should also pay attention to JS errors emitted by the webbrowser, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code:

From:

```
image1.src="../../includes/images/<h:outputText value="#{pelicula.pelicula.imagen1}"/>"
```

To:

```
image1.src="../../includes/images/${pelicula.pelicula.imagen1}"
```